# Update Site Explicitly suffixing content.xml

Tags: eclipse, update-site

My update site looks like

`http://<host>:<port>/jenkins/job/.../target/site/site.xml`

When I try to update eclipse using this update site, eclipse automatically suffixes it with /content.xml.

After which I get a `p2.core.ProvisionException` stating `unable to read repository`.

What can be done to avoid this additional appending of content.xml causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally include the `site.xml` in the update site URL so just specify:

```
http://<host>:<port>/jenkins/job/.../target/site/
```

Eclipse should look for `site.xml` (old style update site) and `content.xml` (p2 repository style update site).

Comment: The problem we are facing is that in one of the eclipse installation the update site is automatically getting appended with `content.xml` ie. if we give `http://<host>:<port>/jenkins/job/.../target/site/` as update site URL it fails with 'unable to read repository' exception with no repository found at `http://<host>:<port>/jenkins/job/.../target/site/content.xml` (Note: content.xml is automatically added). But, interestingly the same update site is working for some other eclipse installation!

Comment: The error messages are incomplete: p2 will only ever say that it couldn't find the ".../content.xml" although it has also tried the other suffixes.